# How can I get the nodeRef of a file in the content store?

Tags: alfresco

I need to get the nodeRef of the document knowing the file on the disk.

Example:
I have a file 2016/6/1/8/0/087dabc7-6b5b-4840-8f3a-d45a55735fac.bin on the disk.
I want to get to the nodeRef of the document inside this file.

I know the path of this file is saved in the cm:content property of the node, but I do not want to get all documents and then iterate over them until I get to right one. Is there an unexpensive way (from the performance perspective) to do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried workspace://SpacesStore/087dabc7-6b5b-4840-8f3a-d45a55735fac ?

Answer (score 0):

The nodeRef and name of the `.bin` file is not the same string. So you cannot just get name of the file and put it as nodeRef, AFAIK.

One thing you can do is to query the database (unfortunately I don't have alfresco right now, so I cannot test the query, but it should be something like this):

```
with tt as(
    select node_id 
    from alf_node_properties 
    where string_value like '%file-name.bin%')
select * from tt, alf_node
where tt.node_id = alf_node.node_id
```

In the result you'd have uuid which is nodeRef.

Another thing you can do is to query with CMIS for documents created at the same time, in your case it's ~ 1st of June 2016 8am.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. Are you sure about it ? I've seen an old forum post about it (https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/general/non-technical-alfresco-discussion/how-can-i-identify-what-document-bin-file-references), but it might be obsolete.

Comment: @Akah, I've just checked in my repo for random document in node browser. Name of the bin file in `cm:content` property is not the same as nodeRef - `sys:node-uuid` property, so now I am 100% sure :)